# Change in session id availability in WebAuthenticationDetails between Spring Boot 2.4.4 and 2.5.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We were updating our Spring Boot application from 2.4.4 to 2.5.2, and ran into an issue where the `.getSessionId()` from the `WebAuthenticationDetails` object returned null in the new version. However, the session id from `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()` did return a session id (in both instances).

We have a front-end SSO, so we use the `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter()`.

We looked through the documents, but have not found where the change is coming from.

What changed, and what do we need to do to ensure the session id is properly present?

##### Probable Relevant Dependencies

**Running with Spring Boot v2.4.4, Spring v5.3.5 (session id present)**

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security -> 2.4.4
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.4.4 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.5 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.4.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.4.5
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.4.5
|         +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.4.5 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.13.RELEASE -> 5.3.5 (*)
```

**Running with Spring Boot v2.5.2, Spring v5.3.8 (session id missing)**

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security -> 2.5.2
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.2 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.8 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.5.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.5.1
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.5.1
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.8 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.8 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.8 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.8 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.8 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.8 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.8 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.8 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.8 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.5.1
|         +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.5.1 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.8 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.8 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.8 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.8 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.8 (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.8 (*)
```

##### Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http.addFilterAfter(httpdAuthFilter(),
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(getPersistanceFilter(),
            SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(getSecAwareFilter(),
            SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        ;

    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .maximumSessions(-1)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

  }

  @Bean
  public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher()
  {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
  }

  @Bean
  public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry()
  {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()
  {
    final List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add(preauthAuthProvider());
    return new ProviderManager(providers);
  }

  @Bean(name = "preAuthProvider")
  /* package */ PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider()
  {
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider =
        new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceWrapper());

    return provider;
  }

  @Bean(name = "httpdAuthFilter")
  public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter httpdAuthFilter()
  {
    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter =
        new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter
        .setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    return requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;
  }
```

##### Application Initializer

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
  /**
   * @see org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer#onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext)
   */
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
  {
    servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));
    
    servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);
    servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);
  }
```

##### Obtaining the WebAuthenticationDetails

(note: null checks removed)

```
SecurityContext secureContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication auth = secureContext.getAuthentication();
WebAuthenticationDetails webAuthDetails = (WebAuthenticationDetails)auth.getDetails();

String sessionId = webAuthDetails.getSessionId();
```

##### RequestContextHolder

```
String rchSessionId =
        RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
```

The sessionId from the `webAuthDetails` returns null in 2.5.2, but the correct sessionId in 2.4.4. The session id from the `RequestContextHolder` is correct in either version.

We look up some information based upon the session id.

Comment: Can you share how you are using the `WebAuthenticationDetails`?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, I added the code for how we are obtaining the session id to the question. We use the session id to retrieve some other information is linked to the session id. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Why don't you open an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

Comment: It's important to note the difference between `auth.getDetails().getSessionId()` and `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()`. The first will give you the Session ID that was received in the authentication request. In other words, it's the session you provided when logging in (if any). The second will give you the Session ID for the current request. Is the goal to retrieve the Session ID that was used during login? And if so, are you including a Session ID when making your authentication request?